# Python try and except logic when returning data from an API

Tags: python-3.x, api, csv, urllib

I am trying to use an API to store data into a CSV file.

I am querying the API / loading the data using the following:

```
def load_data(id):
    with urlopen('url' + str(id)) as response:
        source = response.read()
        data = json.loads(source)
        return data
```

Which is retuning a dict like:

```
{'name': 'Blah',
'address_1':'Street', 
 'address_2':'Town', 
 'website':'www.blah.com'}
```

I am then trying to iterate through a list of target id numbers to retrieve the data like so:

```
for x in targets:
    data = load_data(x)

    try:
        data = load_data(x)

        name = data['name']
        address_1 = data['postalAddressLine1']
        address_2 = data['postalAddressLine2']
        website = data['website']

    except KeyError as e:
        pass

    with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:

        # Declaring the writer 
        data_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        # Writing the headers 
        data_writer.writerow(['name', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'website'])


        # Writing the data 

        data_writer.writerow([name, address_1, address_2, website])
```

The problem I am having is that a data point is missing on some of the iterations, e.g. on loop 2 there is no website, which is causing `KeyError` and therefore crashing the code - so I added in the `try` and `except` to catch this.

But now it seems that I am only returning data for the ids which have all of the above data points.

What I would like to do is return all of the data possible and ignore/fill in blank values where there is a `KeyError` 
So I am wondering is my logic set up correctly and how can I achieve the above goal?

Please let me know if this is not worded very well!

**Edit**
My code wasn't writing each row of data as I had the writer in the wrong part of the loop. Updated code with the write structure and Roland Smith's answer to handle missing value.

```
empty_value = 'TBC'
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:

    # Declaring the writer 
    data_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    # Writing the headers 
    data_writer.writerow(['name', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'website'])

    for x in targets:
        data = load_data(x)

        try:
            name = data.get('name', empty_value)
            address_1 = data.get('postalAddressLine1', empty_value)
            address_2 = data.get('postalAddressLine2', empty_value)
            website = data.get('website', empty_value)

            # Writing the data 

            data_writer.writerow([name, address_1, address_2, website])

        except KeyError as e:
            print(e)
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is to add missing keys manually:

```
required = ('name', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'website')

data = load_data(x)

for key in required:
    if key not in data:
        data[key] = 'not available'
```

Now your `data` at least contains all the keys you expect.

Alternatively, you could use the `default` argument of the `get` method:

```
    ds = 'not available'
    name = data.get('name', default=ds)
    address_1 = data.get('address_1', default=ds)
    address_2 = data.get('address_2', default=ds)
    website = data.get('website', default=ds)
```

Comment: Thank you, both worked well! I opted for the second way although did not need to add `default=` and just needed the variable ds. I now seem to only be getting one row of data which is annoying so need to figure that out!